# Wildcard dictionary search in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to search for a particular pattern of words (i.e. a pattern containing wildcards) against the spell check dictionary built in Excel?

```
Debug.Print Application.CheckSpelling("hel*")
```

For example, I want the above code to return `True` if I am searching for `"hel*"`, because some actual words do match this pattern, e.g. "hello", "hell" etc.

However, this does not work as intended: it returns `False`.

Comment: Application.CheckSpelling will not correct or offer to correct a misspelled word, it only returns Boolean. In your case "Hel*" will be considered as string that is why False is returned. If you have Custom dictionary of your own then you it can return True.

Comment: "Hel*"(H in upper case) returns a TRUE but "hel*"(h in lower case) returns a FALSE. I've made this update to my initial question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had a little fun writing this one... It works with single-character wildcards, i.e. `?`. It doesn't work with multi-character wildcards (`*`), but I still thought this was an interesting path forward.

Warning: This uses recursion, and execution time increases exponentially with the number of `?` in the input string!

```
Function CheckSpellingWithWildcards(ByVal s As String)
    Const wildcardChar As String = "?"
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim firstWildcardPos As Long
    firstWildcardPos = InStr(s, wildcardChar) 'Find first wildcard
    If firstWildcardPos = 0 Then
        'No wildcards left — look it up in the dictionary.
        CheckSpellingWithWildcards = Application.CheckSpelling(s)
    Else
        CheckSpellingWithWildcards = False
        For i = 97 To 122 'a to z. Adjust if you need e.g. çæøåéëï as well
            Mid(s, firstWildcardPos, 1) = Chr(i)  'Replace wildcard with letter
            If CheckSpellingWithWildcards(s) Then 'note: recursion!
                'Found a match! Get out.
                CheckSpellingWithWildcards = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
?CheckSpellingWithWildcards("Hel?")
True
?CheckSpellingWithWildcards("Hel?o")
True
?CheckSpellingWithWildcards("Hel?p")
False
?CheckSpellingWithWildcards("Comm?nica?ion")
True
?CheckSpellingWithWildcards("C?mm?nyca?ion") '30 seconds later...
False
```

Comment: Thank you! I was actually interested in multiple wildcards. I will work on your method and proceed. Thanks again!